# printing certain positions from a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

If my matrix is like `[[1,2,3,4],[5,3,6,2],[7,7,7,2],[9,7,5,3]]`

and I want to print the positions of the second row so that the output would look something like this:

```
[1][0]
[1][1]
[1][2]
[1][3]
```

i think i need to use a `for` loop but not sure exactly how.

thnx

Comment: you actually want to print what you put as an example or do you want to print the values associated with those indexes?

Comment: So what have you tried? Consider a for loop.

Comment: Enumeration is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Python provide built-ins for nearly every purpose. Use the `enumerate` function and string formatting:

```
for i, j in enumerate(matrix[1]):
    print '[1][{}] contains {}'.format(i, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,3,6,2],[7,7,7,2],[9,7,5,3]]
[print(x) for x in matrix[1]]
```

or

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,3,6,2],[7,7,7,2],[9,7,5,3]]
print(matrix[1])
```

or

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,3,6,2],[7,7,7,2],[9,7,5,3]]
index = 1
index_two = 0
for x in matrix[index]:
   print(str(x) + " from " + "[" + str(index) + "][" + str(index_two) + "]")
   index_two += 1
```

The difference between the three is simply formatting. The second will print the values in `matrix[1]` like this: `[5,3,6,2]` the first will print like this

```
5
3
6
2
```

and the third like this.

```
5 from [1][0]
3 from [1][1]
6 from [1][2]
2 from [1][3]
```

Hope this was what you were looking for

Comment: @marmeladze You did something wrong. That doesn't work.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi when i hit run, eveything seems ok to me. (if you mean catching errors - e.g. indexerror, i ve intentionally didn't put it)

Comment: I see now. You're using each method for each row.